# Failed to load module "colorreload-gtk-module"

Tags: arch-linux, thunar

On Archlinux, when I try to load Thunar from shell I get this error:

> Gtk-Message: 20:29:21.004: Failed to load module "colorreload-gtk-module"

and frequently Thunar stop work. I don't know how to fix this problem, please help.

Answer (score 6):

I had this problem too, but had no interest in installing the actual module, since I don't actually know what it is for anyway (and other answers indicate it's a KDE-related module, whereas I'm using Xfce).

I found the module was referenced from `~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini`, with a line like:

```ini
gtk-modules=colorreload-gtk-module
```

Removing this line (or commenting it out with #) got rid of the annoying warning. :-)

Comment: Yes - - thanks.  Installing libcolorreload-gtk-module.so from a KDE package (on Fedora) pulls in 77 other KDE desktop packages that I don't want.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem too... I was able to fix it by doing a

```
locate libcolorreload-gtk-module.so
```

and then (for me)

```
    sudo cp /opt/kf5-5.75.0/lib/gtk-3.0/modules/libcolorreload-gtk-module.so /usr/lib/gtk-3.0/modules/
```

Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: I alread have it at  /usr/lib/gtk-3.0/modules/ but the message happens anyway

Answer (score 2):

The warning is harmless and can be ignored, but if you want to silence the warning the module is provided by the kde-gtk-config package in Arch.

https://archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/kde-gtk-config/files/

Just install that package and the warning should go away. This is very unlikely to be related to Thunar crashing though.

Comment: I just installed with pacman that package, the message is still there. Should I relogin?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this command to figure out what package you need:

`pacman -Fx colorreload-gtk-module`.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error while working with python opencv.
For me installing kde-gtk-cofig solved this problem. on Fedora:

```
sudo dnf install kde-gtk-config
```